# face_recognition and dlib trying to use cuda while no nvidia card is installed

Tags: python, face-recognition, dlib

im trying to load the face_recognition on my intel w/ igpu, after isntalling and reinstalig dlib i havent be able to make it run, here is my code

```
import face_recognition
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-ca17cc6b8bdb> in <module>
----> 1 import face_recognition

~/anaconda3/envs/tfs_cpu/lib/python3.7/site-packages/face_recognition/__init__.py in <module>
      5 __version__ = '1.2.3'
      6 
----> 7 from .api import load_image_file, face_locations, batch_face_locations, face_landmarks, face_encodings, compare_faces, face_distance

~/anaconda3/envs/tfs_cpu/lib/python3.7/site-packages/face_recognition/api.py in <module>
     24 
     25 cnn_face_detection_model = face_recognition_models.cnn_face_detector_model_location()
---> 26 cnn_face_detector = dlib.cnn_face_detection_model_v1(cnn_face_detection_model)
     27 
     28 face_recognition_model = face_recognition_models.face_recognition_model_location()

RuntimeError: Error while calling cudaGetDevice(&the_device_id) in file /tmp/pip-install-x2i2y7s0/dlib/dlib/cuda/gpu_data.cpp:201. code: 100, reason: no CUDA-capable device is detected
```

i have uninstalled the two libraries like this

```
pip3 uninstall dlib
pip3 uninstall face_recognition
pip uninstall dlib
pip uninstall face_recognition
```

then i install them like this

```
pip3 install -v --install-option="--no" --install-option="DLIB_USE_CUDA" dlib
pip3 install face_recognition
```

but the librarie just pop ups the same error, any advice in order to solve this would be great!

thanks for reading

Comment: Did you manage to solve this? I'm trying to resolve the same issue.

Comment: yes man it is solved, the solution was to install in the base enviorement the cuda 10.x and cudnn 7.6.x  and then you should install the dlib, switch to your  virtual enviorement and install again the dlib

Comment: Even I have the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

The same issue in colab, switch it to any GPU solve the problem, seems that face recognition works only if present GPU.